# How to make a wanted number of folders on my desktop

Tags: python

So I had an idea to make a program where I enter a number of folders and one equal name for those folders and the python program makes those folders on my desktop. But my code doesn't work.

```
num = int(input("How many folders do you want: "))

name = input("What folder name do you want: ")
lolo = "C:/Users/..myname/Desktop/" + name + "{}"

for i in range(num):
   new = open(lolo.format(i), "w")
```

Comment: google how to make new folders with python, then look at your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using `open` is to open a file.

To make a folder i recommend using the `os` library.

```
import os
for i in range(num):
    os.mkdir(lolo.format(i))
```

Then it will make your folders. You should also have some error validation to address what it should do if a folder already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your path is correct, try using `os.mkdir` instead of `open`

```py
import os

num = int(input("How many folders do you want: "))

name = input("What folder name do you want: ")
lolo = "C:/Users/..myname/Desktop/" + name + "{}"

for i in range(num):
   os.mkdir(lolo.format(i))
```

Here's some info about it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-mkdir-method/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import os
num = int(input("How many folders do you want: "))

name = input("What folder name do you want: ")
lolo = "C:/Users/..myname/Desktop/" + name + "{}"

for i in range(num):
   os.makedirs(lolo.format(i))
```